# how to pass text in model.predict

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk, vectorization

I have vectorized data to convert data from text to numerical and then I used LogisticRegression() model to train that data and test the data. Done everything, and now I have done the model. predict(), how can I pass text values inside it? because if I do I get an error
[how do I pass new text to model.predict() CLICK HERE FOR CODE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwJDP.png)

Comment: can you share some code to show what you mean

Comment: yeah man code is also there click on the perma link in the question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This could because of discrepancy of the shape of x_new and what the model is expecting. Try to transpose x_new or show the shape of x_new if possible.

Comment: it's just that i want to pass text values in the model.predict() , i did the vectorisation to the text but the issue comes - ValueError: X has 10 features per sample; expecting 1026   .                       So is there a way i can change the features of X which is the text that i vectorised from 10 features to 1026 . IN Simple words i want to pass the new text to  model.predict